# Best Method to Create a Table in Report Builder 3

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, tablelayout

I am trying to replicate a word document as a report in Reporting Services 2008r2.

I need to create a table, with some cells spanning more than 1 column. Essentially it's a 3 column table, but sometimes the 2nd column should fill the space of the 3rd.

I can't find a good way of creating this in Report Builder 3 - I have tried using a table and matrix but cannot achieve what I want.

This report is for 1 record, I want a table of data related to a record and do not want to create textboxes and rectangles and arrange them neatly to get what i want.

Each field should have its own row - but some of those rows will be split with 2 values.

Does anyone have a good method to create what I want? Please don't tell me this isn't the 'norm' and how to do the normal way - I need to replicate an existing layout.

Comment: If you could provide some screenshots of the existing report to show your requirements that would be very helpful.

Comment: Also, some sample data in the question to expand your requirements would also be useful.

Comment: Thankyou Ian, I have managed to solve my issue by deleting the 'Header' row from the table. And then using it like a normal table in an office app, I have also ensured that my Dataset only contains 1 row (which may have had some bearing on my issue)

I realise my question was terrible and am a bit embarrased about it now - posted it before leaving the office last night in a rush.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the update. I wouldn't worry - maybe not the best question ever, but not even the worst I'll see today! Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by deleting the 'Header' row from the table. Then using it like a normal table in any MS Office app, I have also ensured that my Dataset only contains 1 row which may have had some bearing on my issue...